# ERR code EAI_AGAIN when npm i on a new project folder on Ubuntu VPS

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm

**Environment:**
VPS with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-29-generic x86_64) with NGINX & PM2.

In the root folder I have a folder for a MEAN stack project, which is running perfectly well.

**When do I get Error:**
I needed to add another project on this VPS, so created another folder in root folder.
Added the code files, including package.json (without package-lock.json).
And tried to run npm install.

It gets stuck at  `idealTree:xxxxx: sill idealTree buildDeps`

And after a long time gives error:

```
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo
npm ERR! errno EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! request to http://registry.npmjs.org/nodemon failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org
```

**Tried the below:**

```
npm config rm proxy 
npm config rm https-proxy
```

`npm config set registry registry.npmjs.org --location=global`

`npm install registry.npmjs.org`

I also tried to start fresh by deleting package.json and then

```
npm init -y
and tried to install packages one at a time
npm install --save-dev nodemon
```

Nothing works.

Please help, I am not an Ubuntu or NPM expert.

Am I missing anything here? What should be the correct method to add a new MEAN stack project on an existing VPS running another project?

Comment: definitely a networking issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using wsl2 Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS distribution, I encountered the same error

I tried the following -

```
sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf
```

and then added the below line in the file opened by the nano editor

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

and saved the file.
After that, the issue was resolved and I was able to install Express.
Hope this helps.